# Can PCA provide contextual correlation between features and a target label?

Tags: correlation, pca

I was exploring some of the projects I've done years ago in high school, and my current understanding of Principal Component Analysis differs from what I have performed back then.

---

***Experiment:*** Our project was to find a correlation between a certain acquired value, $x$, from each subject group, and three other features $a_1, a_2, a_3$ (all differing per group). Our experiment was performed for 9 subject groups. Hence, our data was written in a standardized 4x9 matrix, $B$.

What I have done then is to get a Covariance Matrix $S=\frac{BB^T}{9-1}$, and then define an orthogonal matrix $P$ that consists of the eigenvectors of $S$ and a diagonalized matrix $D$ that consists of the eigenvalues of $S$ by following: $S=PDP^T$.

After calculating the weight of each eigenvalue $(w_i=\frac{\lambda_i}{\Sigma_{i=1}^4\lambda_i})$, we normalized the corresponding eigenvector by the eigenvalue with the highest weight. We related the values of the latter three rows of $P$ to $a_1, a_2, a_3$.

The four normalized eigenvalues varied, with $\lambda_4=0.83$. We concluded that the eigenvector of $\lambda_4$, explains 83% of the variability of the data, and observed that $v_4=<-0.49, 0.45, 0.50, 0.55>$.

Hence, Our conclusion was that $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are all negatively correlated to $x$ with roughly $1:1$ ratio.

---

***Question:*** After learning more about PCA, it seems to me that PCA focuses more on combining important features and reducing dimensions, but not on explaining correlations between features. I wonder whether my application of PCA then is harshly incorrect, or that my current understanding isn't quite grasping the legitimacy of the experiment.

Any input or insight is appreciated.